# Two web servers on a LAN with dynamic IP with ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: dyndns, dynamic-ip

My situation is so that I have two different ubuntu server with apache and DNS server installed on them each of which serves and hosts a couple of websites.
Before I had static IP's for them with port forwarding but now I have just an ADSL dynamic IP at my new place!

I have my router (D-Link) connected behind to the ADSL router. How can I solve this problem and resolve dynamic IP's so that I do not need to configure servers every day?
I read a little bit about DynDNS and would like to know how can I have ddclient installed without having DYnDNS account? IS there any free solution for my problem on Linux?
How can I do that?

Comment: Are both the servers connected to the same router? In that case you can configure your router to assign static IPs to these servers

Answer (score 0):

You can use ddclient with free services such as [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html).